# Solr: "rord() is not supported over Points based field"

Tags: solr

On a collection of documents representing **products**, I have a `visits` and `average_rating` fields defined with:

```xml
<field name="visits" type="plong"/> 
<field name="average_rating" type="pdouble"/>
```

I'd like to influence the search results to boost the ones that have lots of *views*, but also the ones having a good *rating*.
Trying to use **dismax** with: `bf=recip(rord(visits),1,100,100)`, I get the error message:

```
rord() is not supported over Points based field visits
```

In order to achieve my intention, I thought about combining both: `bf=recip(rord(visits),1,100,100)` and `bf=recip(rord(average_rating),1,100,100)`, however both fields gives the same error.

Am I doing something wrong? Would this be the right approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually need `rord` to achieve what you want to do? Since you have a direct value that you can use, would applying recip directly to that value work as you'd like?

Comment: @MatsLindh You are probably right! Thanks!